# How to make a collapsable accordian

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience

I would like to have an accordion with one section that when the user will click it, it will open up and when they click on it again, it'll collapse.
I tried following this guide:
https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/accordion/#site-main-content
but I get the following error:
`No COMPONENT named markup://svg found : [markup://c:myComponent]: Source`

I then delete the `<svg>` tags but it doesn't really look good. I can't see the arrows like in the documentation and I tried adding an onClick on the `<section>` tag so I could write a javascript function and toggle it but it doesn't seem to pick up on the clicks. This is what I have:

```
                <ul class="slds-accordion">
              <li class="slds-accordion__list-item">
                <section class="slds-accordion__section slds-is-open">
                  <div class="slds-accordion__summary">
                    <h3 class="slds-accordion__summary-heading">
                      <button aria-controls="accordion-details-01" aria-expanded="true" class="slds-button slds-button_reset slds-accordion__summary-action">
                        <span class="slds-truncate" title="Accordion summary">Accordion summary</span>
                      </button>
                    </h3>
                    <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-button_icon-border-filled slds-button_icon-x-small slds-shrink-none" aria-haspopup="true">
                      <span class="slds-assistive-text">More Options</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div aria-hidden="false" class="slds-accordion__content" id="accordion-details-01">Accordion details - A</div>
                </section>
              </li>
            </ul>
```

Comment: Why not use https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:accordion/example

Answer (score 6):

Short answer

Use [lightning:accordion](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:accordion/example). This saves you the trouble of figuring out how to get the SVG to look just right.

Longer answer

You can use [lightning:icon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:icon/example) or [lightning:buttonIcon](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:buttonIcon/example) to display those SVG elements. However, this usually means you have to pay attention to the various classes and make sure you set the attributes correctly. This is often troublesome and will usually result in the final solution not looking like the example.